# convert csv to sqlite but i don't know if column valid

Tags: python, sqlite, csv

i want white function in python to convert csv to sqlite. in csv, i have 4 columns Setting State Comment and Path. Sometimes the real Path is in the next column or two next columns not every time in Path column.

```
def csv_to_sqlite(csv_file, sqlite_file):
    # Connect to the SQLite database
    connection = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    # Read the CSV file
    with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        headers = next(reader)

        # Create the table in the SQLite database
        cursor.execute(f'CREATE TABLE data ({", ".join(headers)})')

        # Get the index of the "Path" column
        path_index = headers.index("Path")

        # Insert the data from the CSV file into the SQLite database
        for row in reader:
            modified_row = row.copy()

            # Check if the "Path" column starts with '\'
            if re.match(r'^\\', modified_row[path_index]):
                cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO data VALUES ({", ".join(["?" for header in headers])})', modified_row)
            else:
                # Search for the first column that starts with '\'
                for i in range(path_index + 1, len(headers)):
                    if re.match(r'^\\', modified_row[i]):
                        modified_row[path_index] = modified_row[i]
                        cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO data VALUES ({", ".join(["?" for header in headers])})',
                                       modified_row)
                        break

    # Commit the changes and close the connection
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```

but i get error

```
    cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO data VALUES ({", ".join(["?" for header in headers])})', modified_row)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 4, and there are 5 supplied.
```

i expect get db like csv and not error

Edit:
i try to solve this problem from pandas

```
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=',', encoding='cp1252')
```

i get error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 18, saw 5

this is my data [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeD5m.png)

example the problem [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7CaZ.png)

Comment: Hard to say without the data, but it looks like certain lines contain more than 4 columns. Could you also post some of the csv data? I suspect some column values also contains a comma `,` character. You could try using the CSV Lint plug-in for Notepad++ to check the data file for these type of errors https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint

Comment: i have 4 columns Setting State Comment and Path. Sometimes the real path is in the next column not every time in my column. you can write for me function use pands and in Path all start whit \
I get the CSV from GPO in automatically

Comment: delete line 18 for a try, I think the interpreter doesn't lie. There must be some issue in your csv.

Comment: i know i have problem but the problem  is the  Sometimes the real path is in the next column not every time in my column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check what encoding of the file to use with pandas. After that, you will skip lines with an error. Good luck

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The error is an evidence that the current row has 5 columns while the header row only has 4. You should ignore excess columns by limiting the used length of the row:

```
cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO data VALUES ({", ".join(["?" for header in headers])})',
               modified_row[:len(headers)])
```

Comment: if re.match(r'^\\', modified_row[path_index]):
IndexError: list index out of range
i get error

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably due to the number of values in `modified_row` being different than the number of columns in `data`. This is likely because the code is appending extra values to `modified_row` when searching for the first column that starts with `''`.

You can try to only include the values for the columns in `data`.